# change the font size for fragment in xml

Tags: android, android-fragments, font-size

I have an Android code that uses a fragment to create a setting page. The fragment has a minimal xml for the fragment like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/setting_fragment_items"
    android:name="com.aa.bb.Fragments.SettingsFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</fragment>
```

This is my question:
Is it possible to change the font size of text for this fragment in the above xml file? I tried adding for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/setting_fragment_items"
    android:name="com.aa.bb.Fragments.SettingsFragment"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</fragment>
```

But it didn't have any effect.

**Update**

Based on the comments I looked and saw two files  under `xml` folder under `res` folder"

[image]

here is the content of each:

`provider_paths.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

`setting_fragment_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="1x"
        android:dialogTitle="Sizes"
        android:entries="@array/save_size"
        android:entryValues="@array/save_size"
        android:key="@string/size_id"
        android:summary="1x"
        android:title="Default Save Size" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="TheOne"
        android:dialogTitle="Folder Name"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:key="@string/folder_name"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:summary="/Sub/TheOne"
        android:title="Folder" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: there must be some widgets too in that fragment ?

Comment: the only related item I can see in the project is "SettingsFragment.java". Where should I look for the widgets that you are referring to?

Comment: Look at the code for SettingsFragment.java. It should show the XML layout file used for that fragement.

Comment: What made you think that "fragment" tag has an attribute "textSize"? I'm pretty sure there is no such attribute for fragments and Android simply ignores it, which is expected. Instead, you should look at the SettingsFragment layout and set the text size for all text views which are used there.

Comment: @TJ1 if you look closely there should be an xml folder in your res folder. Open it I am sure there are different module xml's that are being used in settings. e.g pref_sync, pref_data etc etc.

Comment: @Umair yes I found the xml folder I tried to set font size in a file called setting_fragment_layout.xml, but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks, yes it does show the xml layout as I mentioned above (reply yo @Umair) but still the size of the font does not change.

Comment: @TJ1 no you are still doing it wrong. :) If you want to set the text size open any xml file with name pref_sync etc and there you can see widgets declared. There you can change the text size. not in setting_fragment_layout

Comment: @Umair thanks again :) I cannot find any xml file with name pref_sync.

Comment: @TJ1 can you post any of your xml file which is in xml folder of your res directory.

Comment: @Umair I updated the question with info you were asking.

Comment: @TJ1 yes now as you can see in your setting_fragment_layout.xml, edittextpreference is there now you can change it's text size. you have to give the attribute android:style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" or give textsize programatically.

Comment: @TJ1 another way is to include a layout in your let's say edittextpreference add attribute android:layout="@layout/layoutName"  and in that layout use simple widgets like edittext or textview etc.

Comment: @Umair I get an error that says: attribute `android:style` not found.

Comment: @TJ1 did you tried other way ?